# Apply jQuery UI CSS Across Entire Site

Tags: jquery-ui, user-interface

I was wondering - is it possible to apply the jQuery UI CSS to an entire site without having to apply it individually upon elements?

So, for example, instead of having to do:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" />
```

to all my buttons, I instead have some sort of class applied at at top-level DIV which will change the entire site whenever it can be (any element that jQuery UI can handle). If it's not possible, it's no big deal, but it would be great if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can just call

```
$('button').button()
```

from your script to select all `button` elements using jQuery and apply the jQuery UI button theming to them. See, for example, the sample code on the [jQuery UI button demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/).

Comment: Ah...cool. Of course, my site has to load some stuff all "AJAX-y" so it doesn't apply to those buttons. Any suggestions. (Either way, I'm marking this answer as correct.)

Comment: BTW, you meant ':button' as your selector, right? (I'm assuming so.)

Comment: @JasCav Just do `$('button').button()` after every replacing of HTML with AJAX.

Comment: Or it should be `$('input:button').button()` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could apply it on the `$(document).ready(function(){$("*").addClass("ui-state-default")});`

This is not tested, so don't take my word for it.

Comment: this is NOT a sane way of doing things… and i LIKE insane ways of doing things.